# Is it possible to get a server code from Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I am implementing Facebook Login using the Objective-C SDK. I make a call like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager;

// inside a method:

[self.loginManager logInWithPermissions:permissions
                   fromViewController:[self topMostController]
                   handler:loginHandler];
```

and the handler gets a `FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult`. Everything works but the result only contains an access token. Although I am using HTTPS, it seems wrong to share this access token with my backend. Is there a way to get a server code like I do in the web flow, so that I may exchange it for an access token on the backend?

Comment: _“it seems wrong”_ - why? _“Is there a way to get a server code like I do in the web flow”_ - no, AFAIK that is only available with the web flow.

Comment: I was hoping someone would ask that. Thank you. Why? Because it seems wrong from a security perspective. TLS is TLS but what if it’s misconfigured or something? Why transmit an access key when you can transmit a code that needs to be exchanged with a private secret that only I hold. But I don’t know much about security and I guess FB is comfortable with this? Just trying to make sure I’m not missing something when it comes to something so important/basic.

Comment: Google, for example, lets you get a code from their iOS SDK. But it requires non default config. Maybe the way these non-browser environments are set up make the whole code flow unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, Facebook is pretty much okay with this. The web flow gives you the explicit choice whether you want token, code or both - but for their native mobile SDKs, they did not implement anything like that, AFAIK. And I don’t think “what if TLS fails” is much of a point to make here; that access token has to be send elsewhere as soon as you use it to make any API calls (to Facebook’s servers) - so what if TLS somehow failed on _that_ connection then? If that was a real issue to be concerned about, then those apps should not even be using tokens internally.